# What are the standards to implement scale bar?

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography, scale

I am working on .osm data files, and now I want to implement scale bar for available data.

Logically I have created the scale pixel is to geo location. I want to know whether there is any standard to display this scale bar.

Comment: You should use graphical scale